# Clone/duplicate an existing GameObject and its children

Tags: c#, copy, unity-game-engine, gameobject

Is there a C# way in Unity to duplicate an existing GameObject and all of its children?  In my case, I have an empty GameObject with a number of Text objects as children and I would like to create a copy of them all, including relative positions, text values, font, colors, etc....

Prefabs won't work easily because I want to copy the object including its current state.

Answer (score 24, accepted):

The [`Instantiate`](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Object.Instantiate.html) function is used to clone any GameObject and its hierarchy.

```
public GameObject rootObj;

void Start()
{
    GameObject duplicate = Instantiate(rootObj);
}
```

Answer (score -4):

```cs
    using System.Collections;
    using System.Collections.Generic;
    using UnityEngine;
    
    public class main : MonoBehaviour
    {
        public GameObject hk;
    
        void Start()
        {
            hk = new GameObject("I am hk");
        }
    
        void Update()
        {
            hk = new GameObject("I am hk");
        }
    }
```